# loadnibnamed not loading subviews

Tags: swift, xib

I am trying to load a xib filed called "AddProgramView" using loadnibnamed when a user presses a button. I created the xib in storyboard, placed various subviews within the xib view, and hooked up outlets to a corresponding swift file named AddProgramView. When I load the xib, none of the subviews appear. They are all missing. Help? Here's my code

Within my main view controller:

```
@IBAction func addProgram(sender: UIButton) {

    if let _ = addProgramView {
        addProgramView!.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.window!.frame.origin.y + self.window!.frame.height, self.window!.frame.width, CGFloat(325))
    }
    else {
        let addProgramViews = NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("AddProgramView", owner: self, options: nil)
        addProgramView = addProgramViews.first as? AddProgramView

        addProgramView!.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.window!.frame.origin.y + self.window!.frame.height, self.window!.frame.width, CGFloat(325))

        window?.addSubview(addProgramView!)
    }

    window?.bringSubviewToFront(addProgramView!)

    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3, delay: 0.0, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveEaseOut, animations: {
        self.addProgramView!.frame.origin.y -= CGFloat(325)
        }, completion: nil)
}
```

The AddProgramView.swift file:

```
class AddProgramView: UIView {


    @IBOutlet weak var nameField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var cancelButton: UIButton!

    @IBOutlet weak var instructionsLabel: UILabel!
}
```

Comment: Could you include some code about the `window` you declared?

Comment: It's just the app delegate window. The custom view appears within that window but doesn't have the subviews

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First check, if you have your class name declared in the view itself, not in the file owner.

[image: class name]

If not, do it. Then try it again.

**Another option** is to create IBOutlet in your *AddProgramView.swift*

```
@IBOutlet var contentView: UIView!
```

and remove the class name from the view and add it to File's Owner.

[image: owner's class name]

Connect contentView by right-clicking at the File's owner:

[image]

Then create init methods like this:

```
class AddProgramView: UIView {
    @IBOutlet var contentView: UIView!

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        commonInit()
    }

    func commonInit() {
        NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("AddProgramView", owner: self, options: nil)
        self.addSubview(self.contentView)
        self.contentView.frame = self.bounds
    }
}
```

And now you can use the AddProgramView wherever you want. Either by init(frame:)

```
let addProgramView = AddProgramView.init(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 30))
```

or you can use them directly inside storyboard by adding UIView and set them class to *AddProgramView* (No extra line of code, storyboard will call init(coder:) for you)

[image: storyboard]

I've created example project for you - [CustomView project](https://www.dropbox.com/s/7faciz1ne5ktu6f/CustomView.zip?dl=0)

Comment: I had already tried the first option correctly. So I tried the second option. Am I supposed to add each IBOutlet within commonInit(), or just the contenView, which has all of my subviews? In particular, let's say i have an IBOutlet called myTextField that is a subview within contentView. Am I supposed to add myTextField as a subview of contentView within commonInit()? I'm guessing not, but it's not working. There are two issues:

Comment: I had already tried the first option correctly. So I tried the second option. Am I supposed to add each IBOutlet within commonInit(), or just the contenView, which has all of my subviews? I'm guessing not, but it's not working. There are two issues:
(1) the placement of the contentView is offset to the left from where it is supposed to be. Calling self.contentView.bounds = self.bounds not working right
(2) the subviews still don't appear by just adding contentView as a subview within commonInit(). If I add my subviews explicitly, they lose all constraints specified in the xib file. Any ideas?

Comment: I have updated the answer for you. You should use frame instead of bounds. There is also the example project, take a look.

Comment: Switching to frame solved issue (1). Your test project worked. But I swear I am doing exactly the same thing, yet my project does not work. Here is a slimmed down version of my project. Can you identify what's wrong? https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/35854077/TestXib.zip

Comment: I've found a problem. You have to connect the first view in stack. https://www.dropbox.com/s/t0ltdlg9p5n5gzc/Screenshot%202015-09-23%2015.14.26.png?dl=0 . Then your view will be loaded properly. Nevertheless, your solution of showing view is bad. You should create another controller and present him as modal.

Comment: Thanks! That did it. I want to be able to reuse a calendar that i have displayed in the main view, rather than having to reload a whole new view and new calendar. I think that creates a more seamless user experience. Anyway, thanks again!

Comment: Thanks for answer, I one doubt why we need to self.addSubview(self.contentView) after init view with nib.

Comment: @AlešOskarKocur What if I have to add that custom view programmatically on the view instead of creating a dummy view.

Answer (score 1):

Double-check that you don't have a size class specified in your xib file. It should say Any/Any at the bottom of the editor window.

Comment: Why would this matter?